# How can I send arbitrary data through a push notification?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to send some data to a Windows Phone 8 app. I want to implement this through push notifications.

I'm currently serializing my data as JSON and place it in the `wp:Param` field in the push notification. While my app is running in the foreground, I receive the notification just fine, can deserialize the field and use the data.

However, when my app isn't in the foreground, the toast won't be displayed at all. When I remove the `wp:Param` field from the notification, the toast will appear again, so I'm assuming WP8 doesn't like me putting JSON data in the `wp:Param` field.

How can I send my data and still have the toast appear if my app isn't in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

The value provided in `wp:Param` has to look like a URL for Windows Phone to process it and display the toast.

The [valid formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_gdr3) are:

- `/page1.xaml` – Defines the screen to navigate to in the app when the app starts. The string must begin with a "/".
- `/page1.xaml?value1=1234 &amp;value2=9876` – Defines the screen to navigate to when the app starts, along with name/value pairs of info. The string must begin with a "/".
- `?value1=1234 &amp;value2=9876` – Contains name/value pairs of info passed to the default start screen of the app. The string must begin with a "?".